# CSS and Javascript files arent load in my HTML file at root folder - Openshift

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, openshift

I'm using OpenShift free to make my term paper. My issue is that, in my root folder, I have the files: rankAplus.html, todo.js and dashboard.css. When I call todo.js and dashboard.css in my file rankAplus HTML, I get this error (not found 404 - browser error). When I look inside of my element dashboard at browser, the file type was changed, from text/css to text/html. The same thing occurs with my JavaScript file. The files are the same folder. What I need to do? Does someone know how to solve this?

I'm using Node JS to create server at openshift.
And im using references like AngularJS and Bootstrap.

My folders structure at server openshift:

../repo/
. . .  rankAplus.html
. . .  todo.js
. . .  dashboard.css
.

Server.js Routing for rankAplus on callback:

```
function showRank(req,res)
{
    res.sendfile('rankAplus.html');
}
app.get('/showRank',showRank);
```

On rankAplus.html header, i call to todo.js and dashboard.css this way

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="todo.js"/>
 <link href="dashboard.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I've been tried:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../todo.js"/>
 <link href="../dashboard.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and...

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/todo.js"/>
 <link href="/dashboard.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but, nothing works.

Anyone?

Comment: The changed file type is not a mystery at all. When you get a 404 error, the file info you see is for the "Not Found" page, not the file you're trying to retrieve. So really the only problem is why you'd get the 404 error in the first place.

Comment: You shouldn't write `<script type="text/javascript" src="todo.js"/>`, certainly not in a HTML file. Change it to `<script type="text/javascript" src="todo.js"></script>`. Not sure if that solves all your problems though.

Comment: i made it and i get the same error: 

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://aplus-tccinatel.rhcloud.com/dashboard.css"

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://aplus-tccinatel.rhcloud.com/todo.js"

Comment: And you're sure the files are at those locations?

Comment: In the root? And is rankAplus.html located there too? I mean, 1) the server says "Cannot GET" when I try to access them there, and 2) you said they were in a subdirectory named repo.

Comment: @MrLister look... I dont know if these files are at the root folder, however, i'm sure that files are at the same folder, because i never change the place for them, when i access my server by RHC SSH,  and navigate through the folders, i see that these three files, are at the same folder, that is the same folder of my service (server.js). This is the first time that i use openshift, i dont know what happens there. I'm lost

Comment: @DiegoMoura have you tried `<link href="./dashboard.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">` that '.' is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put complete URI like,

```
    <link href="http://localhost/repo/dashboard.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

path is case sensitive

Dashboard.css is different then dashboard.css on linux and unix based systems.